# jQuery getting the id of button inside other elements populated by loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an html elements completely populated by foreach loop. How do I get the value of the button for instance the delete button? Or how to get the link edit button?

```
@foreach($data as $d)

          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
            <a href="#" class="cab" id="thumbnail{{ $d->id }}" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus">
              <img src="{{ asset('images/cabinet.png') }}" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail" >
              <p class="text-center">{{ $d->description }}</p>
            </a>
          </div>

           <!-- loaded popover content -->
           <ul id="popover-content" class="list-group{{ $d->id }}" style="display: none">
             <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Share</a>
             <a href="#" id="edit{{ $d->id }}" class="list-group-item open-modal" data-value="{{ $d->id }}">Edit</a>
             <button class="list-group-item mt-sweetalert-delete" value="{{ $d->id }}">Delete</button>
           </ul>


        @endforeach
```

Comment: I think, if you have id. You can use this selector in class: 
 jQuery(this).contents().find('strong');

Comment: You're generating an ID inside of a `for` loop. This will create duplicate `popover-content` IDs, which is invalid markup, and will cause problems with JavaScript selectors. Consider using a class instead.

Comment: Can you expand upon what you mean by "how do I get" ?  in what context are you trying to get it? Do you have some example pseudocode for what you're trying to do (you can write it up with with "here I get the id of the button" for the bit you're not sure about how to do)? Sometimes the context really helps us help you :)

Comment: use a class to target the element and use this.val

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target the desired elements with regular jQuery / JavaScript selectors. It depends when exactly you want to grab the elements, but considering your elements are generated dynamically, you'll want to hoist the scope and make use of **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**.

In the following example, I attach an event listener to the `<body>` tag, which is useful as it will always exist on the page at page load. This listener looks for clicks on any `<button>` element, and if it finds one, it logs the button's `value`. Because the handler is on the `<body>`, this will work for buttons that are dynamically generated.

This can be seen in the following example (in which I turned on the `display` of the `<ul>`), which triggers when `Delete` is clicked. The element you are clicking on is stored as `e.target`:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.matches("button")) {
    console.log("Clicked: " + e.target.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
  <a href="#" class="cab" id="thumbnail{{ $d->id }}" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus">
    <img src="{{ asset('images/cabinet.png') }}" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
    <p class="text-center">{{ $d->description }}</p>
  </a>
</div>

<!-- loaded popover content -->
<ul class="list-group{{ $d->id }} popover-content" style="display: block">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Share</a>
  <a href="#" id="edit{{ $d->id }}" class="list-group-item open-modal" data-value="{{ $d->id }}">Edit</a>
  <button class="list-group-item mt-sweetalert-delete" value="{{ $d->id }}">Delete</button>
</ul>
```

Also note that you're creating your `popover-content` ID inside of a loop, which will provide invalid markup. This invalid markup will also cause JavaScript selectors to only return the first result when you try and target those elements. I've switched this to a class in my example.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your explanation at the bottom helps me a lot :-D thanks